# IDLE not able to open python file

Tags: python, python-idle

I have been using IDLE and Python 2.7.11 on windows 10 for some time now.  And just today I went to run a python program that I had created and it wouldn't run.  Instead I got a pop-up box that displayed an error.  It worked fine in the past, so is it because the version I have now is not compatible with windows 10?

EDIT:
the error said that this PC was unable to run this app.

Comment: Did it display any *particular* error?

Comment: You need to tell the *exact* path for the file and *exactly* how you tried to run it.  It sounds like the message is from windows, and that IDLE was never run, making your title incorrect ;-).